# primefaces 3.5 p:treenode header

Tags: primefaces, tree

I work with primefaces 3.5 and I have a treetable with some treenode kinds. Each treenode has more one column.

I want to display a header in each treenode column.

I tried this, but the header doesn't display.

This is the xhtml

```
 <p:treeTable value="#{mttoJornadasAreaMaquinista.arbolJornadas}"  var="jornada" nodeVar="node" >     
      <p:column>

      <p:treeNode  type="totalinforme" rendered="#{jornada.nombre == 
         'totalinforme'}" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"  >

             <p:column   style="margin-right: 20px;">

                <h:outputText style="margin-right: 20px;" value="Total 
                   Mercancias" />
             </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Total Minutos Conduccion" style="margin-right: 20px;">

          <h:outputText  style="margin-right: 20px;" value="# 
                 {jornada.totalMinutosConduccion}" />
             </p:column>

           <p:column  style="margin-right: 20px;">
            <h:outputText style="margin-right: 20px;" value="# 
              {jornada.totalkmsMaquinista}" />
         </p:column>        
     </p:treeNode>     
     </p:column>

   </p:treeTable>
```

This is the header

```
<p:column headerText="Total Minutos Conduccion" style="margin-right: 20px;">                 
      <h:outputText  style="margin-right: 20px;" 
value="#{jornada.totalMinutosConduccion}" />
     </p:column>
```

How can I display a header in each treenode column?

Comment: The treetable does not work with treenodes, only columns. Adding a treenode inside a column won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question. Can I work with treenodes and columns?. My var has 4 elements and I have to display them in columns  with a header

Comment: That is what a treatable does... without the explicit treenodes. Check the PF showcase